# Regarding longest increasing subsequences in permutations of n elements

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, permutation-cycles

I was trying to solve a problem wherein I had to find the number permutations of $n$ elements which have a longest increasing subsequence (LIS) of length $m$. Ideally, I'd want to have a function $F(n, m)$ where $n$ denotes the number of elements being permuted and $m(<n)$ denotes the length of the LIS we require, and the the function returns the number of permutations which have a LIS of length $m$.

Comment: How big is $n$ and how fast do you want it? There is always the generate all permutations and find the LIS approach which has complexity $O(n!log(n)).$ Other approach is using RSK algorithm an noticing that LIS is the same as biggest part.

Comment: @Phicar I was wondering if I could get an analytical solution for arbitrarily large $n$, actually. The problem that I am out to solve has to do with partially ordered sets generated by permutations and to determine the "height" of the thusly generated partial orders. The height of the partial order is the same as the longest increasing subsequence of the corresponding permutation, so I thought I'll take the permutation approach.

Comment: I think this is a hard problem, perhaps i am wrong but you can get just estimates coming from Erdos theorem. See the book "The Surprising Mathematics of Longest Increasing Subsequences" by Dan Romik